# PEReader not found

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

[I get this error...](http://pasteboard.co/NX6oKwt.png)
It's a blank install of the SDK, haven't done anything else with it.

Google search wielded no results and I don't really know what could've caused it... I just followed the tutorial and tried to build. Running Windows 8.1-64 bit.

This is the error for people that can't see the image;

```
Error   1   The "GenerateBGAgentManifestV2" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.PEReader, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.PEReader, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.WindowsPhone.Build.Tasks.GenerateBGAgentManifestV2.PopulateAgentsFromProjectReferences(Dictionary`2& ListOfBkgndAgents)
   at Microsoft.WindowsPhone.Build.Tasks.GenerateBGAgentManifestV2.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
    PhoneApp1
```

Comment: The link shows a *completely* different error message.  Don't make it too "blank", this is a Visual Studio assembly.  Normally present in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies, go see if it is there.

Comment: Link fixed, sorry. There is no folder PrivateAssemblies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Was answered here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/59535617-9f52-4b4a-9ce8-d17e806178d8/pereader-dependency-not-found?forum=wpdevelop)
Apparently it's a known bug...

Comment: Broken link. Please include the text next time, as well as the link.